# "aria-label" attribute of the HTML content got removed when injected into the Outlook compose form

Tags: outlook-web-addins

We are building an Outlook addin which injects some HTML into the email or calendar appointment compose form.
We are trying to add "aria-label"s to some of the images so that they can be read by the screen reader appropriately. However, we see those labels are gone after being injected into the compose form.
Wonder is this expected? Does Outlook remove any aria-labels injected into the compose form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML Email is *not* the same as HTML5 (or very close even). I personally think MailChimp's [HTML Email reference puts it best](https://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/html-email-basics/):

> This reference assumes you’re a front-end web designer with an intermediate working knowledge of HTML and CSS. You’re comfortable coding in and using HTML tables for structure, and working in coding standards that were state-of-the-art in 1999. Feel free to crank up a little TLC or Goo Goo Dolls to get into the spirit of things.

Given that HTML Email clients barely support `style` attributes, it is safe to assume they won't support HTML5's [`aria-lebel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute).